# Object Oriented Method Bridge

Tags: php, oop

Several resources in my system use the concept of Object Collections, based upon Java's Collections.

This Collection Class (abstract) provides basic functionality to another concrete class, called Lists, which allow to find Objects through Collection's Indexes.

I'll use as example, my HTTP Headers Class to explain.

I have, in its Constructor a instance of this Lists Class. Every HTTP Header Field is added in the Collection through **Headers::addHeader()** method.

Obviously, I have a *getter* method called **getHeaders()**, which return the Collection's **Storage**, not the Collection's **Object**.

So, if I need to list the Headers outside this class, I just have to call **$obj -> getHeaders()** and I have an ArrayObject with all Objects added.

Alright!

But, recently, came up the necessity to use one of Lists methods, **Lists::find()**, which finds an Object without even know Object's name or its specific position in Collection's Storage.

Since Lists object is in a private property, Headers::getHeaders() returns the Collection Storage and I don't want to violate the encapsulation, by making the property a public one, I can't access this method.

Everything I code, besides the functionality, must be visually elegant, and create another getter method, let's say getHeadersLists() would produce an invocation like:

```
$obj -> getHeadersLists() -> find( 'foo' );
```

This is ugly!

So, I quickly added a __call() in Headers Class and it worked fine:

```
$obj -> find( 'foo' );
```

But someone I know (and he's very versed in Object Orientation theme) told me this is wrong.

My argument was purely focused on readability, and he counter-argued "in Object Orientation, Magic Methods and Readability cannot coexist".

So what? What should I do to create this "bridge" between these two classes, without use a _call() and preserving the Object Orientation's principles?

I know, I could return the Collection Object in Headers::getHeaders() and use something like:

```
$obj -> getHeaders() -> find();
```

But something I learned about Object Orientation is responsibility. The responsibility of this method, as its declaration said, it's to return all the Headers added and not an outside object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I intent to hit you with Uncle Bob's Single Responsibility Principle a.k.a (S.O.L.I.D's big S). Which you can read more at [Principles Of OOD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) article. Also for directly answering your question [Tom Dalling's very nice article and example](http://tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-single-responsibility-principle/).

[image: Single Responsibility Principle. Acknowledgement I have no rights or claims on this image.]

The problem when you hide getHeaders() function call which returns and object of type **Lists** then it looks like you are calling the object and it has a function called find "which it should not have" as it is not his responsiblity to find correct headers.

I can understand your responsibility approach.

You say: When I call getHeaders() I should not be forced to manipulate the result further to get what I want.

This suggestion of yours is *completly correct*. But to achive this result hiding getHeaders() function call with syntatic sugar is *completly wrong*.Because it is going to mislead me.

Consider me as a third party reading your code, I would immediately assume there is a find() function of that class which is very misleading. Also I would reject this find() function as finding from list of headers is not expected responsiblity from the object thats just a unnecessary add-on or a mistake. So your colleague is also correct :D.

I Belive circumstances that forces you to call **find()** to be able to use the **Headers** type object are to blame for here.

My suggestion for your dilemma is something like this.

1. This object should most definetly have a function called getHeaders(). Do not change that. It should return all headers.
2. Make a second funciton called getRelatedHeaders("foo") or *getFooHeaders()* which calls getHeaders() inside in a encapsulated manner than uses find("foo") on them and returns your "foo" headers.

Now there is only one small sugestion remaining my friend. I believe your discussion provokes a far more interesting question which you and your team mate should ask.

Almost always, if you need to need get an object's some property and act on them. Then you should also be able to encapsulate that functionality to that object/class too. It is almost always a code smell when you get an objects property and use it to do something then put it back.

> Why is that object not doing his responsibility but you are
>   manipulating his properties for him ?

Thank you for your time, I hope I helped you in someway :D.

Answer (score 0):

That's why there is a "protected" scope, in PHP, like other O.O. Programming languages.

In case you know, a "protected" member can be access by descendant classes, but, cannot be accessed as public.

As a suggestion, I usually don't use "private", but, "protected" instead, for the same reasons, as your post.

Comment: Alright, but the protected visibility will not help in this case because I'm not calling the method in inheritance context. Think in this way: Header **uses** Lists and not Header **is a** List. And by extending Lists my Headers class will become dependent.